Flutter 3.19 - rotate button, is there a better way to code in 2024?
I just have started learning flutter for about 2 weeks, but most of the time i don't like the standard design styles that flutter's widgets provide to us, so.....
I need to create a cart button filled with black color that includes an icon(image) and than rotate button on 45* angle, but icon have to stay as normal.
Example Image of rotated IconButton
So I came up with this solution:
Column(
  children: [
    Transform.rotate(
      angle: 45 * pi / 180,
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
        style: IconButton.styleFrom(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        icon: Transform.rotate(
          angle: -45 * pi / 180,
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/icons/shopping-cart.png',
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 22,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),

The question: is there is a better way to do it?
If I don't add a -45 angle to the icon (image), they would turn together.

Please share image you want to create.

I would say "Is it a correct and best way"-questions are not really on-topic for this website. It's kind of subjective also which is another reason why it's not suited for here. Not sure if https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ maybe is better.

@Ivo is it better now?
I just want to figure out the best way tho.

@DroidFlutter i have added an image to the post

This is a correct way. You can use Custom Painter but it wont be this efficient

Another way to rotate button
RotationTransition(
                turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(0.12),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: (){},
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    child: RotationTransition(
                        turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(-0.12),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Icon(
                          Icons.add_shopping_cart,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ))),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),


You may try this:
 class RotatedCartButton extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: 45 * 3.1415927 / 180, // Rotate the button by 45 degrees
          child: Container(
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: -45 * 3.1415927 / 180, // Rotate the icon back by -45 degrees
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

It will give you result like this:

